# SetInterval Collides When Calling a jQuery Plugin More than Once

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I'm working on a custom jQuery plugin that makes use of SetInterval, but it breaks when it's called more than once.

I have something sort of like this:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.myplugin = function(options) {

        var defaults = {};
        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
    var interval;

        this.each(function() {
            //etc.
            interval = setInterval(function(){ doMyOtherFunc(options); }, 1000);
        });

        function doMyOtherFunc(options) {
            //etc
        }

    }
})(jQuery);
```

Functionality works as expected if I call it once, but if I call it again on a second element it breaks.

```
$('#myelement').myplugin({'option1', 'option2'});
$('#myotherelement').myplugin({'option1', 'option2'});
```

Somehow, the interval in the second instance overrides the one on the previous element, data and all. (But the styling passed doesn't get screwed up.) Is this a weird limitation of setInterval, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is this really your code? I cannot see anything wrong with it (expect that if more than one element would be selected you might get problems). The `interval` variable is local to the `myplugin` function. It cannot be overwritten through another call. Maybe it is a problem with the part in `// etc.`.

Comment: Interesting. Do those two containers overlap at all?

Comment: No, the containers don't overlap at all.

Comment: @felix There isn't anything in the //etc part that interacts with the interval at all. I also tried changing the scope of the interval variable to be inside the this.each method. Same results. It's very strange.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the interval handle private to each element. For this, you could use `$.data`:

```
    this.each(function() {
        var interval = setInterval(function(){ doMyOtherFunc(options); }, 1000);
        $(this).data('myplugin-interval', interval);
    });
```

And you could retrieve the interval this way:

```
$(this).data('myplugin-interval');
```

Comment: That is an issue but should not be the reason for the OP's problem.

Comment: I tried, for testing purposes, declaring the interval handle inside the this.each block, but the same thing happened. Could there be some weird JS quirk that causes it to always be in the global scope or something?